# Python subprocess.Popen compiling in g++ adding .cpp files automatically

Tags: python, c++, bash

If i have a rather large library of files, and want to link them, do i create a bash script and then put that into a python script to get all the files i need for that terminal line i need to use to compile. I don't think im building it properly cause there is no ./test

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
file = open("react3dEngine.txt", "r")

fileList=file.readlines()
file.close()

p=subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall", str(fileList), "-lglut", 
"-lGLU", "-lGL", "-stdio=c+11", "-o", "test", 'main.cpp'], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
p=subprocess.Popen(["./test"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: `-stdio=c+11` didn't you mean `-std=c++11`? You should include any errors you get, also try cutting and pasting the command you build into the command line directly to see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely with `str(fileList)`; you are telling g++ to look for a file named "['foo.c', 'bar.c']" (the stringification of the list).  You should have something like the following instead

```
["/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall"] + fileList + ["-lglut", "-lGLU", "-lGL", "-std=c+11", "-o", "test", 'main.cpp']
```

Comment: -std=c++11 and took off the capture of errors, now i can see that my batch script isn't getting the file path i would have thought readlink -f foo.cpp would have worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`fileList` is a list. Calling `str()` on a list produces a formatted string that includes the brackets, e.g.

```
>>> fileList = ['a.c', 'b.c', 'c.c']
>>> str(fileList)
"['a.c', 'b.c', 'c.c']"
```

so that's not going to work as part of a command line.

Instead you need to pass each of the strings in the file list as an argument. You also need to remove the trailing new lines that might be present in the file that you read with `readlines()` (I don't know the format of your `react3dEngine.txt` file).

Try coding it like this:

```
with open("react3dEngine.txt") as files:
    file_list = [line.strip() for line in files]
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall"] + file_list + ["-lglut", 
"-lGLU", "-lGL", "-std=c+11", "-o", "test", 'main.cpp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    # etc.
```

The `strip()` takes care of any leading and trailing whitespace that might be present in the input file.